# I cannot start Anaconda

Tags: module, anaconda, anaconda-cluster

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/setsoto/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 7, in 
from anaconda-navigator.app.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'anaconda_navigator'

This is what I'm getting when I try to start anaconda and I don't know what happened because it has been working fine

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to come here and SHOUT at us when you're asking for free help to solve your problem.

Comment: Try updating? `conda update anaconda-navigator`